# How to automatically set an adequate zoom level for tiled data from stamen in R

Tags: r, openstreetmap, stamen

I have a project where I need to automatically download data from OSM/Stamen in R. So I also need to be able to automatically set an adequate zoom level for the tiles to be downloaded. It should show sufficient detail given the area of interest. My idea was e.g. to use the extent of the bounding box to set a good level i.e. to define some breaks for the 20 or so levels from OSM which have described "qualitative" breaks on wikipedia, see [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels). So I wondered if there is already something done in this way or if I have to write a function from scratch.

Here is a minimal reproducible example with a manual choice of an adequate zoom level

```
library("ggmap")

# manually choose zoom level
zoomlevel<-12 
# see all zoom levels here: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels

map <- get_stamenmap(bbox = c( -75.18343,5.382292,-74.95132,5.592376), zoom = zoomlevel, maptype = "terrain")


mymap<-
  ggmap(map) + 
  theme_minimal() 

mymap
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of other packages that download map tiles, and `rosm` has an automatic zoom function. It computes this from a bounding box, using an unexported function. For example with your vector bounding box it can be converted into a two-column matrix:

```
> library(rosm) # for extract_bbox
> bbox = c( -75.18343,5.382292,-74.95132,5.592376)
> rosm:::tile.raster.autozoom(
     extract_bbox(
       matrix(bbox,ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)),
     epsg=4326)
```

to give an answer of:

```
[1] 12
```

As an unexported function you can't rely on it to be stable, but you can extract the source code and use that (subject to license). Alternatively you could just use `rosm` instead of `ggmap`, perhaps with `tmap`.

Comment: great! This works like a charm! I added an ifelse statement to avoid the zoomlevel being large than 13 because sometimes there is no data for e.g. 14 and 15 `zoomlevel<-ifelse(zoomlevel>13,13,zoomlevel)`. The rest works just perfect! Thanks!